# dovecot maillog does not run or does not update after error appears

Tags: email-server, dovecot

Dovecot maillog doesn't run after receiving an error like this, is there a solution to handle it? for email to run smoothly only maillog doesn't work, I've tried restarting postfix & dovecot, and restarting vps still the same

```
Nov  6 09:58:24 server1 postfix/postfix-script[655752]: stopping the    Postfix mail system 
Nov  6 09:58:24 server1 postfix/master[655529]:    terminating on signal 15 Nov  6 09:58:27 server1 opendkim[511]:    OpenDKIM Filter: mi_stop=1 
Nov  6 09:58:27 server1 opendkim[511]:    OpenDKIM Filter v2.11.0 terminating with status 0, errno = 0 
Nov  6 09:58:27 server1 dovecot: anvil: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by    pid=1 uid=0 code=kill) 
Nov  6 09:58:27 server1 dovecot: stats:    Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill) 
Nov  6 09:58:27 server1 dovecot: pop3-login: Error: read(anvil) failed: EOF    
Nov  6 09:58:27 server1 dovecot: pop3-login: Error:    net_connect_unix(/var/run/dovecot/stats-writer) failed: No such file    or directory 
Nov  6 09:58:27 server1 dovecot: pop3-login: Warning:    Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill) 
Nov  6 09:58:27 server1 dovecot: config: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1    uid=0 code=kill) 
Nov  6 09:58:27 server1 dovecot: log(655591):    Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill) 
Nov  6 09:58:27 server1 dovecot: log(655591): Warning: Shutting down logging    for 'imap-login: ' with 1 clients 
Nov  6 09:58:27 server1 dovecot:    log(655591): Warning: Shutting down logging for 'imap: ' with 1    clients 
Nov  6 09:58:27 server1 dovecot: log(655591): Warning:    Shutting down logging for 'pop3-login: ' with 2 clients 
Nov  6 09:58:27 server1 dovecot: log(655591): Warning: Shutting down logging    for 'pop3: ' with 2 clients 
Nov  6 09:58:35 server1 spamd[647]:    spamd: server killed by SIGTERM, shutting down
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAqhP.jpg)